# Start the ODE-based curve at a time that is different from 0

Tags: r, ode

I have a system of ordinary differential equations (ODEs) that has been built from the R package "`deSolve`". From the ODEs, Is it possible to run the model so that the variable “y2” starts at time = 5 (instead of time = 0) in the example below?

```
  library(deSolve)
    test <- function(t, y, parms) {
      dy1 <- -2 * y[2]
      dy2 <- 1.25 * y[1]
      list(c(dy1, dy2))
    }
    yini <- c(y1 = 1, y2 = 0)
    times <- seq(from = 0, to = 20, by = 0.01)
    out <- ode (times = times, y = yini, func = test, parms = NULL)
    plot(out)
```

Comment: You want to prescribe values for `y[1]` at `t=0` and `y[2]` at `t=5`? Or both at `t=5`?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. If all you want is to plot `y2` from time = 5 to time = 20, then just plot each line manually rather than passing `out` to `plot.deSolve`. Or do you want to run the model differently? If so, can you clarify exactly what you want?

Comment: Yes, I want to run the model differently so that y2 starts at time = 5.

Comment: Does `y1` also start at time = 5? If not, how do you envisage the model behaving between time = 0 and time  = 5? If you want both to start at time = 5, can you use the same initial conditions?

Comment: No, just `y2` should start at time=5. The model should behave as if the initial condition was 0 at time=5.

Comment: I'm confused. If `y2` only starts at time = 5, how do you calculate `y1` between 0 and 5, given that it is defined in terms of `y2`?